# how to post the data in API from the datatable in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, datatable

The code link for this Ui is in https://del.dog/qwertyqwerty

We have Added two APi in this file.
First one is for  get data
second one is for post data by clicking on Save button.
We have to save the table in api by entering above questions .
We are able to add the row in the table by clicking on add button and re- enter the above question for multiple options.

Having some difficulty with saving the table data.

[image]

Comment: What issue you are getting please add its issue

Comment: how to print table data or add in database??

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code at your line number **1073**. And try to post your data

```
 var body =  jsonEncode({
  'temp_vehicle_no': "${_rowList[0]}",
  'engine_no': '123456',
  'chessis_no': '123456',
  'created_date':  '$time_to_save',
  'client_code' : '$_selectedRoute2',
  'financial_Year' :'${widget.Year}',
  'companyCode' : '${widget.CompanyCode}'
});
_rowList.length > 0 ? postVehicle(body) : nothing ="nothing";
```

Comment: We have added the current data which we was filled at that particular time . which was wrong from our end. We want to save all the entries which we are adding in the table and then save all the table data by clicking on save button . Where the main body key are mentioned in above code. But we are facing issue implementing the position of the data mentioned in the table as you can see in the code .